# Is there a way to see what Javascript functions (the name of the functions) execute in real time in Chrome's Inspector?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events, real-time

For example, pretend there is Javascript code that will execute `someFunction()` when a button is clicked and I click that button. I wonder if there is some way to see that `someFunction()` was just executed. Is there a way to see what functions are executed in Chrome in real time?

If it is the Profiles tab in the inspector that does the trick, how exactly do you tell what functions fire in real time with that?

**EDIT 1/21/2012 12:36p Pacific:** From Brian Nickel's comment below, the Timeline tab in the Inspector is the way to see what happens in realtime, but how do you see the names of executed functions in the Timeline?

Comment: Actual realtime would be somewhat useless, as it would be way too fast to follow. Set *breakpoints* on the code you want to monitor.

Comment: I've seen individual functions listed in the timeline.

Comment: I can't set breakpoints because its not my code and I don't know where to set the breakpoints. hehe. THat's what I'm trying to figure out! @BrianNickel, which timeline is this you are talking about?

Comment: @BrianNickel, aaaaaaaah, indeeed, the timeline seems to be exactly it! I didn't notice that before. Just select only "scripting" at the bottom when in timeline then press the "record" button and see everything that is happening!

Comment: @BrianNickel, I see examples of "Function Call" in the timeline, but it doesn't seem to show the name of the function that was called... Am I missing something? If I could just see the name of the function, that'd be perfect!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Timeline and Scripts developer tool can be used to accomplish this goal.

- Open the developer tools panel and press Record under Timeline to begin tracking activity.
- Trigger the event you are interested in (i.e., in your example, click on the button), then stop recording (or continue to record, but be cogniscent of the amount of data you are collecting).
- Note the entires logged in the Timeline panel.  Find the relevant event, and click the twistie arrow to the left of the timing bar for that event.  This will expose the function calls associated with that event.
- Click on link to the right of the function calls to see the relevant JavaScript.  (You ask for a function name, but keep in mind that the event may be associated with an anonymous function, so there isn't always a name available.)
- If you want to step through the event handler itself, insert a breakpoint at the line after the handler's declaration (presuming the event handler declaration is greater than one line).  Alternatively, expand the Event Listener Breakpoints in the Scripts panel and check off the appropriate event type (as listed in the Timeline panel for the relevant event).  Note that this approach will break on every instance of that event, instead of the sole invocation you are interested in.

If you are running into trouble with minified JavaScript and inserting breakpoints (because each line is so long), here's a tip: open the minified script file in the Scripts panel via the dropdown, then click on <kbd>{}</kbd>.  This will enable Pretty Print, expanding the minified code into something more readable by adding whitespace.  This allows you to insert breakpoints more granularity.  Note that if you now return to the Timeline panel, script references (e.g., `jquery.min.js:3`) now use the pretty-printed line numbers, not the minified, whitespaceless ones.

Comment: I see, it takes you to the lines of code where the function is found. Nice! I see that this works well with unminified code, but if you have minified code that contains everything on one to three lines, then you are out of luck because there may be multiple functions defined on one line. I guess this is the best we have right now. It'd be convenient if it added a column count also, not just the line count. For example, `jquery.min.js:3:56` would be nicer than just `jquery.min.js:3`.

Comment: Actually, there is a trick to working around that.  Please see my amended answer.

Comment: Perfect.  I was thinking the exact same thing but was away from my computer for the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of good utilities you can use: `console.trace();`, `debugger`, etc.

Comment: This doesn't provide a way to see what functions are called in real time without modifying the code.